# Highest high since trade opened

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to get the highest high since trade opened and save it in a variable.
The idea is to initiate a stoploss limit at entry price once the price crossed above 1% profit.

I tried the many barssince and valuewhen combinations but can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
var hh = 0.0, var hhIndex = 0
if strategy.position_size > 0 and high > hh
    hh := high
    hhIndex := bar_index
else if strategy.position_size == 0
    hh := 0.0
    hhIndex := 0   

if bar_index == hhIndex
    label.new(bar_index,high,'Highest High')
```